# Removing sign in cookies on sign out

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having trouble with cookies and getting some weird behavior. For now the cookie are set on sign in like so:

```
document.cookie = "cookie1=" + cookie1 + "; expires=0; path=/";
document.cookie = "basicAuth=" + basicAuth + "; expires=0; path=/";
document.cookie = "cookie2=" + cookie2 + "; expires=0; path=/"
```

That works fine. I have a sign out button in the header and on click it does the following:

```
document.cookie = "cookie1=";
document.cookie = "basicAuth=";
document.cookie = "cookie2=";
```

In the header script I have a simple check to see if `cookie1` is empty and to hide the header nav bar and redirect to sign in if it is:

```
if (getCookie("cookie1") == "") {
    $(".navbar").css({"display":"none"});
    window.location.href = "/signin";
}
```

Right now I am able to log out effectively the first time, but logging back in and logging out again seems not to work properly. I still see the navbar and the redirect seems to only work selectively. Is there a better way to set or delete cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a cookie, you should also add the date and path, and the date should be in the past to remove the cookie, so something like

```
document.cookie = "cookie1=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
```

The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) says

> ...to remove a cookie, the server returns a Set-Cookie header with an
> **expiration date in the past.**   The server will be successful in
> removing the cookie only if the Path and the Domain attribute in the
> Set-Cookie header match the values used when the cookie was created.

Cookies are generally easier to work with in Javascript if you use [helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) that set the name, value, UTC timestamp etc. for you, instead of doing it every time you set or get a cookie.

What you're doing just sets the cookie to an empty string, it's never really removed.

Comment: This works well thank you. I'm running into an issue where it works whenever it's calls from a sub-domain (www.foo.com/bar), but not from a sub-sub-domain (www.foo.com/bar/foobar). Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: I've found the problem I was having and fixed my issue. When called from a sub-subpath (/bar/foobar) it wasn't working because I wasn't specifying a cookie path. So the cookie expiration only worked on that subpath (/bar/), not more generally on the site. This was fixed by seting it to `document.cookie = "cookie1=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/";`

Adeneo, I'm going to leave yours as the answer because it was what the question was asking but want to clarify for others to find if they have the same issue.

Comment: Well, my answer is the answer, you should always have a date and a path when setting cookies